# Blender to Unity: Add Custom Collider to A Low Poly Style Terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I have created a low poly terrain object from Blender using a Plane, displaced and decimated it. I then exported it to Unity as an FBX object. As what I expected, my player simply falls through it since it has no colliders on. I could place a Box Collider on the object, but seeing it is a low poly style terrain with lots of bumps, it'll be pretty awkward to have my player walk straightly even if the ground is slightly raised. Even so, there are mountain areas in my terrain object and box colliders would totally be out of the question.

I was thinking of using the Mesh Collider in Unity. I tried experimenting with it but failed. There are also no clear tutorials online on the said situation. How can I add a custom collider to this terrain so the player can walk to it, plus without using the hastly Box Collider.

Here is my terrain object in Blender:
[image: Terrain Object]

As you can see, putting a box collider is totally impossible.

Comment: Have you tried using a mesh collider?

Comment: Yes what is wrong using a `MeshCollider`? Note that probably you will have to make the terrain "solid" meaning it might need to be extruded so it is not only made of single faces

Answer (score 0):

You can make individual Sphere, Capsule and Box Colliders, hide their Mesh Renderers and then rotate, scale and place them to make something similar to your mesh. However, Mesh Colliders should be your best option, after adding a mesh collider to your mesh, make sure the convex option is NOT checked and also make sure to select the same mesh that the GameObject is using from the Mesh field in the Mesh Collider component.

Alternatively, if you want your collider to be simpler than your actual mesh, you could make a simpler mesh (either with an external program or by downloading the ProBuilder package in Unity), overlay that mesh with the terrain you have, give it a Mesh Collider and then hide its Mesh Renderer component.

I don't exactly understand what you meant by "I tried experimenting with it but failed." Did your character keep falling through? Did the character get stuck? Was the mesh collider generated in an incorrect way? I would be able to help you better if you can give me a detailed explanation.